# FontAwesome 5, any way to use versions 4 icons?

Tags: css, font-awesome

We use `fontawesome v5` in our system but I need a specific icon from the v4 pack. Is it somehow possible? maybe via changing the font-family attribute? For illustration purposes: 
[This is what I need](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/android), [this is what I get](https://fontawesome.com/icons/android)

Comment: Using this link instead of v5 https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css

Comment: @MaxiGui v5 has more icons than 4.7

Comment: @PaulBaiju and ? this is not what he is asking.... He can specify a specific link when he is loading it....

Comment: Here are some answer from similar question but not validate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467856/font-awesome-4-and-5-in-same-page or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732718/font-awesome-two-versions